# SO has difficulty translating time remaining into human words

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, private-beta, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Countdown timer is off by 1 interval](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45825/countdown-timer-is-off-by-1-interval)

I've noticed a few times now that SO seems to have some issues is calculating time accurately:

From pm.stackexchange.com -

[image]

Also, when the elections were running, at 6.01am (my time) it said "Election ends in 1 Hour", and I thought "spiffo!" so I came back promptly at 7.01am and it said "Election ends in 59 minutes", which means that the election *actually* finished in 2 hours time, and I should come back somewhere between 0.01 and 1 day later to see pm.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is a known issue discussed at length quite some time ago.  I'll try to find it. It's unfortunate, but the imprecision is built into the system by design.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Countdown timer is off by one minute.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45825/countdown-timer-is-off-by-one-minute) (yay, I found it!) it's the same round up issue, but scaled up to days.

Comment: @Pollyanna - thanks; I've been searching since you mentioned that and I couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: Although the first issue is due to the issue jeff speaks of below, the second issues addressed by the above possible dupe.

Comment: @Pollyanna - agreed

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a bug, it just means the private-beta-to-public-beta transfer boundary fell on a weekend or some other non-business day when most people aren't working (including us).

So, you can read that as "real soon now, assuming a monday through friday business day occurs in the near future."

Comment: Well... for pm.se then OK, but telling someone that an event (election) is happening in 1 hour is a problem when it's actully happening in 2, and that was a totally automated procedure I believe (because at 8.00am sharp the page changed to completed), and it wasn't on a Monday (I think. Ok it might have been a Monday, but that shouldn't matter in this scenario).

Comment: @far I still checked in a change for you, try it now

Comment: thanks. I'll let you know if I see it again.