# review times are off: "come back in X <units> to continue reviewing"

Tags: bug, review

Same problem described elsewhere for other "come back in <time>.." aspects of the "stack" ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79223/193206) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45825/193206)).

To repeat the descriptions elsewhere: After completing review of 40 "Close votes", I may see "come back in 1 hour to continue reviewing".  So, I do that... and in one hour I see "come back in 59 minutes to continue reviewing".  And again in 59 minutes: "come back in 59 seconds to continue reviewing".

From the first, it should have said "come back in 2 hours..."... and so forth.

Comments in the other posts suggest the issue has been addressed elsewhere - but it remains in time communicated on the [review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

VERY annoying for [some of us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86410/193206).

Comment: You haven't really described the issue here, a screenshot perhaps?

Comment: Well "one hour" really means "between 1 and 2 hours," because of how the time difference calculator works. It does seem a bit odd though

Comment: I think we should round it to a decimal place. Like "come back in 1.4 hours", or be more precise and say "come back in 1 hour, 24 minutes"

Comment: @Doorknow Possibly.  I referenced that in my OP. I'd prefer that you read it before just writing it off.  In this case, I'm referring to a distinctly different place in the workflow.  Comments to the post you refer to suggest the problem was being looked at/addressed in that context.  So this issue is about trying to get it fixed in this new context.

Comment: I downvoted because I am sick and tired of people whining about timezones.  SO is based on UTC, so if you are an active user, why should it be so difficult to know when UTC midnight is

Comment: @RichardSitze I realized you referenced it, however, it is the same issue, and it was not addressed - there is no [status-completed] tag that I see. It's the exact same issue - the time difference calculator rounds down - so I don't see why it's not a dup.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I think you're missing the point, this has nothing to do with timezones but with the rounding used at showing times.